# Checking object property of potentially undefined

Tags: javascript

Say I have the following object

```
var book = {
    title: "Javascript Secrets",
    author: "Dummy Mc Dumm",
}
```

I want to test `book.collection.name`, knowing that `book.collection` can be `undefined`.

How can I avoid nesting tests like this ?

```
if(book.collection){
    if(book.collection.name == "foo")
        // success
}
```

Withouth raising a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logical AND operator (`&&`) is short-circuiting and will skip the second expression if the first is false

```
if(book.collection && book.collection.name == "foo"){
    // success
}
```

See [Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators).

Comment: It will fail if `book` has `collection` property but it's an object array.